# UTF-8 encoding is not added to xml metadata tag by ear plugin 

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am generating the application.xml using the ear plugin. The generated xml does not include UTF-8 encoding. How can I add it.
Please help.

**Expected :**

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Actual :**

```
    xml version="1.0"?>
```

**build file**

```
        ear {
          archiveName = 'AdminGui.ear'  
          deploymentDescriptor {
              displayName = 'AdminGui'  
              webModule(warName, "/admin-web")
          }
        }
```